# Installing CiviCRM on Localhost with Windows and XAMPP for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-buildkit, install, windows, local

Question: How can I successfully install CiviCRM on my localhost running Windows with XAMPP and integrate it seamlessly with WordPress?

Explanation: I am currently working on a local development environment for a WordPress website using XAMPP on a Windows machine. I am interested in incorporating CiviCRM for enhanced constituent management and engagement. However, I am facing challenges with the installation process. I would appreciate detailed guidance on the steps required to install CiviCRM on my localhost and integrate it effectively with my WordPress setup. Any insights into potential pitfalls or best practices for this specific configuration would be highly beneficial.

Background Research: I have try but still can not.

Spec:

- PHP version: 8.0.30
- Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/8.0.30
- PHPMyAdmin Version information: 5.2.1 (up to date)
- CiviCRM Version 5.65 WordPress

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible, it's helpful if you can paste the error message as text rather than as a screenshot. This makes it easier for other people who may have the same issue to search for this question.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message (`Fatal error: Uncaught error: Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found`), it looks like you don't have the [PHP Internationalisation](https://www.php.net/intl) module installed, which is a requirement of CiviCRM.

You can find a detailed list of the requirements in the [installation documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements).

This related question might help you to install this module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242378/fatal-error-class-intldateformatter-not-found

Comment: Thanks, i will try it first